# OracleForms - form_success becomes true in key_commit despite there is database error

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a text item named `oncelik` in my form and also column in the table. I've created `unique index` for the column so records can't be duplicated.

When user enters duplicated data and tries to commit, below code runs in `KEY_COMMIT` trigger and after the line `commit_form;` `ON_ERROR` trigger fires and show the error says something like 'You can't enter duplicated data'

After that commit trigger keeps running and `form_success` becomes true so forms also says **"insert successful"**. And form doesn't reload so it looks like dublicated data inserted (but it's not)

I want to stop commit trigger or make `form_success` false when unique index error fires. Commit code is below, Any advice?

```
    Pre_Commit_Form;
    commit_form;  --this line fires the ON_ERROR
    Post_Commit_Form;     

    if form_success then  --after error this block runs and form says insert success
        ShowMessage(proc,True,'AKA-00303');
    else
        ShowError;
        ShowMessage(proc,True,'AKA-00304');
    end if;
```

Note: I know i can control duplicated data on form but i prefer making database error stop the commit proccess.

Comment: You should place the form_success check after the commit_form and before post_commit_form

Comment: @nightfox79 its just changes the running order, still form_success is true and form says insert successful after the error message.

Comment: do you have an on-error trigger that does something, if you ignore the error in the on-error trigger you won't get a failure anymore

Comment: @nightfox79 Yes i do have a on_error trigger and there is just one ShowMessage line in it, nothing else. It runs after commit_form line and shows the message then key_commit keeps running.

Comment: @Radagast81 I haven't tried that but i put messagebox in that block. It's not working because form_success is true

Comment: @Radagast81 Yes i can put it there but still `form_success` is true and form works like its inserting. I want to stop the process with the error and force user to enter unduplicated data

Comment: @Radagast81 Yes that makes sense but i need to make it for `unique index error` Do you know how can i recognize the specific error. I want to `raise form_trigger_failure` if it is unique index error

Comment: @Radagast81 Ok your last advice solves my problem. I can search about making it for specific error type. Thank you. (You can post it as an answer if you want so i can accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are discarding your error through the `ON-ERROR`-Trigger.

Put a

```
RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE; -- To make your error silent
```

at the end of your trigger to make sure the failure state remains as needed.

To explictily handle your unique key problem you can check for the `ERROR_CODE` in the `ON-ERROR`-Trigger and then `RAISE DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` instead.